AWS ECS mounting ca certificate to the container is it possible
to mount private ca certificates into the containers. In EKS we could mount secrets as files, but I’m not sure that’s possible in ECS. is it possible to mount a certificate to the ECS container .if so how can i achieve to do that using the terraform  . can anyone please help me ?
Not having the idea to carry out anything.

What do you understand by "mounting" a certificate? Passing it into a container?

@Marcin it's a k8s thing where you can populate files based on secrets

You can place the file on an EFS volume, and then mount the volume to the ECS containers. The problem with this is it is a pain to get a file onto the EFS volume. You first have to spin up an EC2 instance, mount the EFS volume on the instance, and then copy the files there. You can't manage files on an EFS volume from the AWS web console.
Alternatively, you could store the certificate in an S3 bucket, or as a Secrets Manager secret, and change the startup script in your container to first copy the file over from S3 to a local file in the container, or write the Secrets contents to a local file, before starting up your application.

thanks for the assistance. can you please git bit a light on how can it be achieved through the terraform

You can create the EFS volume, and mount it to ECS via Terraform, but Terraform can't place files on an EFS volume, so you would have to do that part manually, as I explained in my answer. If you want to do the S3 bucket or Secrets Manager approach instead, most of that could be done via Terraform, except you would still need to update the startup script in your container, which means rebuilding the docker image. If you have a specific approach you want to take, and you have a specific question about how to do that in Terraform, post a separate question on this site asking that.

I personally feel mounting the private certificate in ECS or EKS is not a good approach. The good approach to being serverless is having the private key in the ACM or Secret binary in SecretManager.
If you still want to achieve the same you can mount the EFS and add the certificates to the EFS

there's no such thing as a "private certificate".  If it's a CA cert, the whole point is that it doesn't have to be secret.  The key is only involved in signing other keys, it doesn't need to be distributed.
